# AWS SES not able to get a file attached

Tags: c#, amazon-ses

Using AWS SES service I can't seem to add a file attachment

//                                                                                         Amazon SES
// Requires a AWS account and setup
// Replace sender@example.com with your "From" address.
// This address must be verified with Amazon SES.
String FROM = "*****@gmail.com";
String FROMNAME = "Danny";

```
                // Replace recipient@example.com with a "To" address. If your account
                // is still in the sandbox, this address must be verified.
                String TO = s;

                // Replace smtp_username with your Amazon SES SMTP user name.
                String SMTP_USERNAME = "****";

                // Replace smtp_password with your Amazon SES SMTP password.
                String SMTP_PASSWORD = "*********";

                // (Optional) the name of a configuration set to use for this message.
                // If you comment out this line, you also need to remove or comment out
                // the "X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET" header below.
                String CONFIGSET = "ConfigSet";

                // If you're using Amazon SES in a region other than US West (Oregon),
                // replace email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com with the Amazon SES SMTP  
                // endpoint in the appropriate AWS Region.
                String HOST = "email-smtp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com";

                // The port you will connect to on the Amazon SES SMTP endpoint. We
                // are choosing port 587 because we will use STARTTLS to encrypt
                // the connection.
                int PORT = 587;

                // The subject line of the email
                String SUBJECT =
                    "Amazon SES test (SMTP interface accessed using C#)";

                String attachment = "C:\\20231030.csv";

                // The body of the email
                String BODY =
                    "<h1>Amazon SES Test</h1>" +
                    "<p>This email was sent through the " +
                    "<a href='https://aws.amazon.com/ses'>Amazon SES</a> SMTP interface " +
                    "using the .NET System.Net.Mail library.</p>" +
                    "<p>Last Hours Total was " + txtLastHour.Text + "<p>" + "" +
                    "<p>Yesterdays Total was " + txtTotal.Text + " " + "" +
                    "<p>Total Bad Reads from Yesterday " + txtBadRead.Text + "<p> " + "" +
                    "<p>Total Jackpot from Yesterday " + txtJackpot.Text + "<p> " + "";
            
                // Create and build a new MailMessage object
                MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
                message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                message.From = new MailAddress(FROM, FROMNAME);
                message.To.Add(new MailAddress(TO));
                message.Subject = SUBJECT;
                message.Body = BODY;
                

                // Comment or delete the next line if you are not using a configuration set
                //message.Headers.Add("X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET", CONFIGSET);

                                    
                using (var client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(HOST, PORT))
                {
                    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    // Pass SMTP credentials
                    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(SMTP_USERNAME, SMTP_PASSWORD);
                    
                    // Enable SSL encryption
                    client.EnableSsl = true;

                
                    // Try to send the message. Show status in console.
                    try
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Attempting to send email...");
                        client.Send(message);
                        Console.WriteLine("Email sent!");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("The email was not sent.");
                        Console.WriteLine("Error message: " + ex.Message);
                    }

                }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

To add an attachment for sending with SES, you can use the Raw message action. There is a more detailed [example here in the Example Code Library](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/ses_example_cross_RDSDataTracker_section.html) that does this, and has a .NET version. You should to go to the [GitHub link](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/dotnetv3/cross-service/AuroraItemTracker/AuroraItemTracker/ReportService.cs) to see the full code, but here is the main part, which uses MimeKit to get the correct formatting in the raw message in C#.

```
 public async Task<string> SendReport(IList<WorkItem> workItems, string emailAddress)
{
    await using var attachmentStream = new MemoryStream();
    await using var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(attachmentStream);
    await using var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    await GetCsvStreamFromWorkItems(workItems, attachmentStream, streamWriter, csvWriter);

    await using var messageStream = new MemoryStream();
    var plainTextBody = GetReportPlainTextBody(workItems);
    var htmlBody = GetReportHtmlBody(workItems);
    var attachmentName = $"activeWorkItems_{DateTime.Now:g}.csv";
    var subject = $"Item Tracker Report: Active Work Items {DateTime.Now:g}";

    await BuildRawMessageWithAttachment(emailAddress, plainTextBody, htmlBody, subject, attachmentName, attachmentStream, messageStream);

    var response = await _amazonSESService.SendEmailAsync(
        new SendEmailRequest
        {
            Destination = new Destination
            {
                ToAddresses = new List<string> { emailAddress }
            },
            Content = new EmailContent()
            {
                Raw = new RawMessage()
                {
                    Data = messageStream
                }
            },
        });

    return response.MessageId;
}

/// <summary>
/// Build a raw message memory stream with an attachment.
/// </summary>
public async Task BuildRawMessageWithAttachment(string emailAddress, string textBody, string htmlBody, string subject, string attachmentName,
    MemoryStream attachmentStream, MemoryStream messageStream)
{
    // The email with attachment can be created using MimeKit.
    var fromEmailAddress = _configuration["EmailSourceAddress"];

    var message = new MimeMessage();
    var builder = new BodyBuilder()
    {
        TextBody = textBody,
        HtmlBody = htmlBody
    };

    message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(fromEmailAddress, fromEmailAddress));
    message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(emailAddress, emailAddress));
    message.Subject = subject;

    await builder.Attachments.AddAsync(attachmentName, attachmentStream);

    message.Body = builder.ToMessageBody();
    await message.WriteToAsync(messageStream);
}
```